# div problem why is line break inserted?

Tags: html

I want to display one image which is 300px by 300px and then i want to display some text. Unfortunately the text i want to display begins on the next line after image. This is the bare code :-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="display:inline;"><img alt="a.jpg" src = "a.jpg"/></div>
            <div style="display:inline;">some text which is too long probably a big paragraph</div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can display everything in smooth flow layout?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div>
    <img> text
</div>
```

Just float the image.

```
div { overflow:auto; }
img { float:left; }
```

Comment: of course you would probably need to add some margin-right and margin-bottom to the image so the text does not touch the image.

Comment: @neurolabs Yes, you may also want to add a border to the image, so that its dimensions are clearly distinguishable in case it's an image with a white background (and the surrounding background is also white).

Answer (score 0):

I think the float suggestion is correct but apply to the div in this case ie

```
<div style="display:inline;overflow:auto;float:left;">
    <img alt="a.jpg" src = "VC.JPG"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @El Ronnoco You got it wrong. The `overflow:auto` rule must be applied to the **parent** of the floated element. Also, there is really no need to wrap the image inside a container DIV.

Comment: @Šime Works for me. I kept the `div` and the other style rules in there as I wanted my example to match the OP's existing code as closely as possible.

Comment: @El Ronnoco The `display:inline` rule is overridden since floated elements are automatic blocks. The `overflow:auto` rule has no purpose since the IMG element is not floated.